# C++ Inheritance vector problem (infinite looping+ question of using vector in other class)

Tags: c++, vector

I'm making a surface to let the user to input information and print it out.

And this is what it looks like.

```
main <- menu <- Reservation
             <- BookingManager <- BookingRecord
```

And I create a vector  `vector<string> CompanyName` in Reservation,
This is `outputdataInfo()` that add CompanyName,

```
void Reservation::outputdataInfo()
{
    string CompName;
    cout << "Company Name <-" << endl;
    cin >> CompName;
    Reservation::setCompanyName(string (CompName) );
    cout << CompanyName.at(0) << endl;
    // Use for test and it works
    cout << CompanyName.size() << endl;
    // Use for test and it works
    cout << "End of Reservation, thank you." << endl;
}
```

The setter of CompanyName:(worked)

```
void Reservation::setCompanyName(const string& cn)
{this->CompanyName.push_back(cn);}
```

But now `BookingRecord::outputdataInfo()` wants to print Booking Record.

```
void BookingRecord::outputdataInfo()
{
    cout << "      ----- Booking Record -----" << endl;
    Reservation::printBookingRecord();
}
```

And I wrote like this(unconfirm this is correct or not):

```
void Reservation::printBookingRecord() {
    for (int i = 0; i < CompanyName.size(); i++) {
        cout << " ---- Company ---- " << endl;
        cout << "Name: " << CompanyName.at(i) << endl;
    }
}
```

But CompanyName suddenly looks like it forget anything, or like reset the size.
The result is `BookingRecord::outputdataInfo()`  is printing infinitly non-stop, but nothing happen to the `Reservation::printBookingRecord()`. This is weird beacuse there suppose no for-loop in `BookingRecord::outputdataInfo()`.
And I wanna know how to print data with (`Reservation::printBookingRecord()` is called by `BookingRecord::outputdataInfo()`, but the vector is at "Reservation")
(or vector can be use in other classes)
Big thanks :)

**Source Code** (kinda bit long sry)

```
//
//  main.cpp
//
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include "Menu.h"
#include "Reservation.h"
#include "BookingManager.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    Menu m;
    Reservation R;
    BookingManager BM;
    char choice;
    do {
        choice = m.menu();
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 'R': case 'r':
            R.outputdataInfo();
            break;
        case 'B': case 'b':
            BM.outputdataInfo();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid Alphabet. Please try again." << endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (choice == 'R' || choice == 'r' || choice == 'B' || choice == 'b');
    return 0;
}
//.....................
//  Menu.h
//
#include <iostream>
#ifndef Menu_h  
#define Menu_h  
class Menu {
public:   //Accessibility as public
    char option;
    char menu();
};
#endif
//.....................
//  Menu.cpp
//
#include <iostream>
#include "Menu.h"
using namespace std;
char Menu::menu() {
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "        BNC Exhibition Tour in European Cities" << endl;
    cout << "               Exhibition Recruitment         " << endl;
    cout << "                                              " << endl;
    cout << "Please type:" << endl;
    cout << "R -> for Reservation Page" << endl;
    cout << "B -> for Booking Manager Page" << endl;
    cout << "And Press ENTER." << endl;
    cin >> option;
    cout << "" << endl;
    return option;
}
//.............................
//  Reservation.h
//
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#ifndef Reservation_h  
#define Reservation_h  
class Reservation {
private:
    vector<string> CompanyName;
public:   //Accessibility as public
    void outputdataInfo();
    void setCompanyName(const string& cn);
    Reservation();
    ~Reservation();
    void printBookingRecord();
};
#endif
//.....................................
//  Reservation.cpp
//
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
#include "Reservation.h"
void Reservation::outputdataInfo()
{
    cout << "Please input detail information first :" << endl;
    string CompName;
    cout << "Company Name <-" << endl;
    cin >> CompName;
    Reservation::setCompanyName(string (CompName) );
    cout << CompanyName.at(0) << endl; //it works
    cout << CompanyName.size() << endl; //it works
    cout << "End of Reservation, thank you." << endl;
}
//////////////////////// S E T T E R ////////////////////
void Reservation::setCompanyName(const string& cn)
{
    this->CompanyName.push_back(cn);
}
//////////////////////// S E T T E R ////////////////////
Reservation::Reservation() {}
Reservation::~Reservation() {}
/////////////////////// P R I N T ///////////////////////
void Reservation::printBookingRecord() {
    for (int i = 0; i < CompanyName.size(); i++) {
        cout << " ---- Company ---- " << endl;
        cout << "Name: " << CompanyName.at(i) << endl;
    }
}
//.............................
//  BookingManager.h
//
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#ifndef BookingManager_h  
#define BookingManager_h  
class BookingManager {
public:   //Accessibility as public
    char option;
    void outputdataInfo();
};
//..........................................
//  BookingManager.cpp
//
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include "BookingManager.h"
#include "BookingRecord.h"
using namespace std;
void BookingManager::outputdataInfo() {
    BookingRecord BR;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "      ----- Booking Manager -----" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Please type:" << endl;
    cout << "B -> for Booking Record" << endl;
    cout << "And Press ENTER." << endl;
    cin >> option;
    cout << "" << endl;
    do {
        switch (option)
        {
        case 'B': case 'b':
            BR.outputdataInfo();
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid Alphabet. Please try again." << endl;
            break;
        }
    } while (option == 'B' || option == 'b');
}
#endif
//...........................................
//  BookingRecord.h
//
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Reservation.h"
#ifndef BookingRecord_h  
#define BookingRecord_h  
class BookingRecord : public Reservation {
public:   //Accessibility as public
    void outputdataInfo();
};
#endif
//..........................................
//  BookingRecord.cpp
//
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Reservation.h"
#include "BookingRecord.h"
void BookingRecord::outputdataInfo()
{
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "      ----- Booking Record -----" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "     Print all the information..." << endl;
    Reservation::printBookingRecord();
}
// END
```

Comment: Try to provide an example code we can run in one go. This code should provide the class definitions, notable methods and members.

Comment: There's some weirdness in your code. I'm particularly interested to know how `BookingRecord::outputdataInfo` calls `Reservation::printBookingRecord`, when `printBookingRecord` is apparently non-static and `BookingRecord` and `Reservation` are apparently unrelated. I expect the explanation is that you have multiple variables called `CompanyName` and are setting one but printing the other. I don't have an explanation for the infinite loop. Anyway need to see more code, in particular declarations of the various classes and how they relate to each other.

Answer (score 1):

So you have two `CompanyNames` in your code.

One is here, part of the `R` variable.

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    Menu m;
    Reservation R;
```

And the other is here

```
void BookingManager::outputdataInfo() {
    BookingRecord BR;
```

`BookingRecord` derives from `Reservation`, so it also contains a `CompanyName`.

I think it's pretty clear that you are adding a name to the `CompanyName` in `R` in `main` but printing out the `CompanyName` in `BR` in `BookingManager::outputdataInfo`.

The class design looks wrong to me.For instance there's a lack of parameters to your methods. Surely `BookingManager::outputdataInfo` should take a `BookingRecord` as a parameter to allow the caller to specify which `BookingRecord` they want to output. Just declaring a `BookingRecord` as a local variable in `BookingManager::outputdataInfo` doesn't make any sense.

Before you rush to write a lot of code, try and think about the design of your classes. How the different classes should relate to each other, what member variables they need, what methods they need, what parameters and return types those methods need. Think about this in terms of how your classes model the real world, not in terms of how you are going to implement functionality. That comes later, get the design right first.

Comment: Oh... Got it now... Can constructor in "Reservation" can be helped or something that makes a copy to let others get the same value? Because I still kinda confused now or using array might be a way? Thanks.

Comment: You're thinking about this in the wrong way. Think about the real world, does every reservation have the same company name? So why would you want that in your program? This is a problem in the design and organization of your code, not a problem that will be fixed by tweaking a constructor. Does your program need to deal with multiple reservations? If so then an array of reservations could make sense.